# Can I get my stuff back from a follower after he has left my service?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a follower (Jzargo) and had him carry a bunch of my loot. But I forgot to get it back from him before I sent him home. Now he won't talk to me because I'm in the middle of a quest involving the college and so I can't ask him to join me again.

Is there any way to get my stuff back from him without resorting to pickpocketing (which I tried, but even though it's my things he thinks I'm stealing from him). I am also not very good at it so I can't easily get away with it, and even if I did I wonder if they would now appear as stolen goods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cleanest way to get your equipment back is to complete the current quest. Nobody dies, gets a bounty or tries to kill you. You're in a very unusual situation, possibly the only such situation in the game where an NPC who could be a follower temporarily has the follower tag removed as part of a quest.

Comment: This ended up working just fine. I was afraid that my stuff might disappear if I left it with him too long, but it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

- You could kill him and then take the stuff, obviously losing him in the process and possibly gaining a bounty.
- You could pickpocket him, sell it to then buy it back from a fence to launder it.
- You could finish the college quest/line and then ask him to be a follower again.
- If PC version you could use console to do it (multiple ways), but this would be cheating.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had Illia as a follower but when I accepted a quest from the companions, she left with all my stuff. I tried to pickpocket her but got caught and had to kill her. Still, I got my stuff back and somehow never got a bounty.

So, to answer the question, if you don't mind killing them, that's one way to get your stuff back!